# Moving Average calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, window-functions

```
CREATE TABLE TmpMAVG 
(
    TransID int identity(1,1) not null, 
    Quantity INT not null, 
    Price money null, 
    Amount money null,
    SortId int not null,
    NewAmount Money null
);

INSERT INTO TmpMAVG (Quantity,Price, Amount, SortId)            
    SELECT 500, 12, 0,1
    UNION ALL SELECT 500, 10, 0,2
    UNION ALL SELECT -100, 0, 0,3
    UNION ALL SELECT -200, 0, 0,4
    UNION ALL SELECT -300, 0, 0,5
    UNION ALL SELECT 800, 15, 0,6
    UNION ALL SELECT -900, 0, 0,7
    UNION ALL SELECT -300, 0, 0,8
    UNION ALL SELECT -500, 0, 0,9
  
UPDATE TmpMavg 
SET Amount = Price * Quantity 
WHERE Quantity > 0
```

Expected output Yellows are calculated:

If quantity is positive then
Amount = Price * Quantity
else
Amount = (Sum of All previous Transaction Amount)/(Sum of All previous Transaction Quantity) * Quantity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkN7v.png)

I tried below query. but no luck

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.Amount = (SELECT SUM(Amount)/SUM(Quantity) 
                 FROM TmpMavg 
                 WHERE SortId < T1.SortId) * T1.Quantity
FROM TmpMavg T1 
WHERE T1.Quantity < 0
```

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation of the excel formula would be:

```
select t.*,
    1.0 * (amount - sum(amount) over(order by transid))
    / nullif(quantity - sum(quantity) over(order by transid), 0)
    * quantity as result
from TmpMAVG t
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
If quantity is positive then
Amount = Price * Quantity
else
Amount = (Sum of All previous Transaction Amount)/(Sum of All previous Transaction Quantity) * Quantity